# Bootstrap hiding page content with named anchor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, anchor

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.4 and whenever I use a named anchor to jump to a section on an FAQ page the top part of the page (everything above the anchor) gets completely hidden/ignored/removed.

I am NOT using a fixed header. See the issue [here](http://www.cyberlinkasp.com/newsite/index.html) by clicking on any question under the "Questions Answered" button.

Comment: It is happening because header and other portions of main page are part of index.html but when you click on any FAQ link, it redirects to another page where there is no header in markup

Comment: I see now that is is because I have overflow: hidden; on the container. But that is to keep the footer at the bottom of the page. Seems like there should be a way to do both.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `margin-bottom: -9999px;` on `col-sm-9` and `col-sm-3` to get them same height, you set this `overflow: hidden;` on `.container`.

Instead setting `overflow` to `.container`, set it to first parent (`.page`).

```
.page{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then it wont affect header and footer.

Comment: I see your point, but as soon as the left side navigation scrolls up it is hidden from view and impossible to get too. After I realized the overflow:hidden was the problem, I started looking it up and I think there is no way to do this. Kinda unbelievable and stunning.

Comment: Could you explain more, what are you trying to achieve? Page looked nice with my CSS. What are you trying to do with navigation?